# NodeJS Express not serving '/socket.io/socket.io.js'

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to build NodeJS/Express/SocketIO application.

Imports:

```
var     express     = require('express')
    ,   app         = express()
    ,   server      = require('http').createServer(app)
    ,   io          = require('socket.io').listen(server)...
```

Configuration:

```
app.configure(function(){
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
    app.use(express.session());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});
```

In my Jade template:

```
script(type='text/javascript', href='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
```

But '/socket.io/socket.io.js' is not available when I am trying to reach it on

```
http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js
```

As it says:

> Cannot GET /socket.io/socket.io.js

How do I serve socket.io.js from the installed module?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to copy the client code from an inner Socket.io directory to your public directory.  In Socket 0.9, the path to the distributable files is `node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist`.

Comment: I was about to answer differently, but then realized my project doesn't use express.  I think you've got it right.

Comment: This is not an appropriate method.  While it works, it is not advisable.  Socket.io already has constructs in place to intercept and serve the request at `/socket.io/socket.io.js`.  The code above is failing because the `express` instance is not being passed into the `listen` function of socket.io.

Comment: In socket.io 1.2.0 the build is located at node_modues/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js

Answer (score 5):

You do not have to copy any files, socket.io will take care of the delivery of the file.

```
var express = require('express'),
    app     = new express(),
    server  = require('http').createServer(app),
    io      = require('socket.io').listen(server)
```

Comment: My console is telling me `Warning: express.createServer() is deprecated, express applications no longer inherit from http.Server, ...` You're right though. The correct process is further outlined in https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x

Answer (score 2):

In Express 3/4 you can initialize socket.io like so:

```
var io = require("socket.io")(app.listen(80));
```

Answer (score -1):

There is an error, use

```
script(type='text/javascript', src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
```

instead of

```
script(type='text/javascript', href='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
```