# Node.js Express 3 not serving socket.io.js

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to follow the instructions here

http://socket.io/#how-to-use

However, I seem too dumb to understand why I cannot reference socket.io.jss on the client side. I've read similar posts here but they don't seem right: [NodeJS Express not serving '/socket.io/socket.io.js'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458366/nodejs-express-not-serving-socket-io-socket-io-js)

Here's the full app listing:

```
var application_root = __dirname,
    express = require('express'),
    //Web framework
    path = require('path'),
    //Utilities for dealing with file paths
    pg = require('pg'); //Postgres integration

//Create server
var app = express();


// Configure server
app.configure(function () {
    //parses request body and populates request.body
    app.use(express.bodyParser());

    //checks request.body for HTTP method overrides
    app.use(express.methodOverride());

    //perform route lookup based on url and HTTP method
    app.use(app.router);

    //Where to serve static content
    app.use(express.static(path.join(application_root, 'public')));

    //Show all errors in development
    app.use(express.errorHandler({
        dumpExceptions: true,
        showStack: true
    }));
});


//Start server
var port = 4711;
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port %d in %s mode', port, app.settings.env);
});

//Start socket.io
var server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

Now if I try to reference the client-side js, I get a 404.

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Anyone know why Express 3 is not allowing socket.io to serve its client lib?

Comment: Just a thought, but the src should be prefaced by a slash. `src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"` A relative path could cause the request to fail depending on the current page url.

Comment: I think you are right, but still produces a 404

Comment: I just ran your script as-is with the only two additional lines being `app.use(express.static(__dirname));` to serve the html file for the example, and `server.listen(8080);`. It served socket.io.js just fine. Whatever problem you're encountering probably lies elsewhere in your code. I would recommend starting with a simple example and building off of that, or post a more complete code snippet.

Comment: I have replaced the example with my full script. I get the socket.io start console message, as expected. I added app.use(express.static(__dirname)); but that made no difference. Grateful for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer here

[Socket.io is not served in /socket.io/socket.io.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14258349/socket-io-is-not-served-in-socket-io-socket-io-js)

> Read through http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.listen, note how
>   app.listen is defined.
>
> In short: replace app.listen with server.listen.

Comment: Yep, that would definitely cause that problem... the fact that I added `server.listen()` might have been a clue, but I'm glad you got it figured out. You should accept your own answer now, so other people know the question has been adequately answered.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Stack Exchange won't let me accept my answer for another 9 hours - so I'll do it then. Again, thanks for your help.