# Something wrong with socket.io and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

This is my jade file:

```
doctype html
html
    head
        meta(charset="UTF-8")
        title
        script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
        script.
            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
            socket.on('news', function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
            });
    body
        hello world
```

and this is my app.js

```
var app = require('express')()
var server = require('http').Server(app)
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
app.listen(3000)
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index.jade')
})    
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Socket.io does not work because if I try to get

```
http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js
```

node server responds:

```
Cannot GET /socket.io/socket.io.js
```

I have found this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458366/nodejs-express-not-serving-socket-io-socket-io-js) but does not help. Maybe due to my module version:

```
{
  "name": "venti",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "socket.io": "^1.0.6",
    "express": "^4.6.1",
    "jade": "^1.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Does your index view get rendered (e.g. you see your 'hello world')?

Comment: I'm assuming `http://loclahost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js` the spelling of `localhost` is a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your code. I also got the same error.

I just changed this line

```
var server = require('http').Server(app)
```

to

```
var server = app.listen(3000);
```

and it worked. Make sure to remove `app.listen(3000)` what you already have.